# Forcing scroll positioning with Javascript scrollLeft

Tags: javascript, firefox, scrollbar

I have a set of Javascript functions I use with a table of input elements to enable navigation. Things like keeping track of the currently focused element, and overflowing from the end of one row to the start of the next. I have scrollbar support with a fixed first column by creating one table that is only one column wide as my fixed column and having a scrollbar for the other table.

However, I have been noticing recently, that the default behavior of the scrollbar is a bit deficient. When I navigate to the last column, Firefox leaves that column partially obscured by the scrollbar instead of scrolling far enough to see it. Likewise, once I scroll over so I can see the other part of the last column, when I move on to the next row and the nav code sets focus to a cell in the first column (the frozen table), Firefox doesn't change the scrollbar so I can see all of the first column.

Because of this, I've been looking into how to modify scrollbar positioning using javascript. My table doesn't use a vertical scrollbar, only a horizontal one. So I stumbled upon scrollLeft.

```
document.getElementById("meastable").scrollLeft = 1; // reset scroll to leftmost
```

Unfortunately this seems to only work once in a while. When I enabled Firebug and traced through my navigation code where this line is, it seems to work once in a while, but most of the time, this line will run but the tables scroll left property is unchanged and I can't see a change visually either.

I also set scrollLeft to a high number so it will be set to the maximum as is described in the documentation, and that also does not work (except once in a while).

I use the following code to set up the scrollbar with my table.

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
<table id="meastable" border="1">
```

According to Mozilla's documentation, this seems to be something that originated in IE but now works in Firefox. Does this actually not work in Firefox as the inhouse project this is for will be Firefox only.

So I'm trying to figure out what's wrong. Is scrollLeft known to not work right, or should I go back and see if I've screwed something up in my definition of the scrollbar or something along those lines?

Comment: haha... i read the id as "meatstable"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The containing div is the element with overflow. You need to set the scrollLeft of the div, not the table.